# NuGet package details window missing

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Usually when you click "Install" or "Uninstall" button for NuGet package in Visual Studio it shows up you a window with package details. Recently I clicked "Do not show this window again", how to get it back? Didn't find any settings in Tools->Options->NuGet.

Just click this and you will see what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy and you should expand the **Options** in your display window.

[image]

That is not only for one nuget package but also for all nuget packages.

Comment: Omg, why the hell so simple thing are hidden under options?! Moreover, there is no such checkbox in Settings windows (gear button)

Comment: That is normal that VS quite has some strange options display. And It's none of our business. That is by design :) And . `And since my answer helps you handle the issue, please mark it. And it is kind of you to do that.` And if you have your own ideas, you can [suggest a feature on DC Forum](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=8) to reflect your idea.